# Apple push notification tokens

Tags: ios, push-notification, jwt, apple-push-notifications

my app's apple push notification certificate is expired. Before expiration server used curl.. Now I renewed it and used JWT for sending notification on my server..

Now, I'm trying to send push notifications to users. Can I use the device token from certificate back then or do I have to change the code from app to get new token? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html) in 'Figure 6-6, Managing the device token', if the device token needs no refresh, you can use it with your new backend implementation without any changes needed on client-side.

No matter what, you need to check and send the device token to your server on each app launch to ensure that you have the newest device token.